# How to uninstall "pycrypto"?

Tags: python

how to uninstall pycrypto?

I got an error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto' so I searched on Stack Overflow and someone said

> > > > "WARNING: Don't use pycrypto anymore!
> > > > Use pycryptodome instead, via pip3 install pycryptodome.
>
> But make sure that you don't have pycrypto installed, because both packages install under the same folder Crypto."

So I'm looking to uninstall pycrypto

Comment: `pip uninstall pycrypto`?

Answer (score 0):

use `pip list` or `conda list` to see your installed packages.
From their you should be able to see the correct name of the package.
Afterwards you can use `pip / conda uninstall *packagename*`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following commands to uninstall pycrypto:

```
pip freeze | grep pycrypto

# copy the output say, pycrypto==2.6.1 and run uninstall command.

pip uninstall pycrypto==2.6.1
```

**Note**: pip freeze will list all the installed python packages and grep will narrow it down to only pycrypto package

Comment: True, albeit this assumes the user has access to GNU / Unix tools.  Let’s hope, to make life easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can go in your python site-packages folder (or wherever your packages are installed) and simply delete them. pip uninstall should work too.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily uninstall every pip package by using

```
python3 -m pip uninstall <package name>
```

or if pip shortcut is setup (most commonly)

```
pip uninstall <package name>
```

to get a package name you can run

```
pip list |grep <some filter>
```

the <some filter> is a query you want to search e.g. crypto

for your package it should be

```
pip uninstall pycrypto
```